# Iterating through a PHP-Array with $.each

Tags: php, jquery

I built an Ajax request with jQuery where - at the end of the PHP file, which is called - an array is the result:

```
echo json_encode(array('status' => 'true'));
```

Within my jQuery in the calling file, I would like to read if the `status` is `true` and I tried it with this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "logic.php",
        data: "receiver=" + receiverIds + "&subject=" + subject + "&msg=" + msg,

        success: function(data){                        
            $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
                alert(elem.status);
            });
        }
});
```

but the alert is always `undefined`. When I insert this line before the `$.each`:

```
$("#additionalTextDiv").html(data);
```

I get the following result: `{"status":"true"}`

But why is the each function not working properly?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to parse the response into a JavaScript object first. The result of the PHP is not a JSON encoded array, but a JSON encoded object. Then, in case you iterate over it with `$.each`, `i` will be the property name and `elem` the value, but you can also access it with `obj.status` once you parsed it.

Comment: FYI ```json_encode(array('status' => 'true'));``` does not translate to an array in JavaScript. It's more likely to end up in a JavaScript object that looks like this ```{status: "true"}```, which you would NOT want to loop over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `dataType` property of the options object you are setting in your AJAX call to `json` so the JSON string gets parsed into a JavaScript object:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "logic.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
```

`.ajax()`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Your `$.each()` loop works just fine, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/54pB9/

However if you are going to loop through a lot of records a `for` loop will perform faster:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(data[i].status);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/54pB9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the message is still 'undefined'. I just added the `dataType = 'json',` I have to keep the json_encode-PHP function right? Without the json_encode in the php-script i have no result either. Or should i change the php-script and remove the array() ?

Comment: @Torben Check to see that the JSON returned from the PHP script looks like this: `[{"status":"true"}]` because this is the necessary format for your code to work; an array of object(s). Put `console.log(data);` at the beginning of your `success` callback function and see what it outputs in your console.

Comment: It says Object and when i click on the arrow on the left i see status: "true" ... php-code still looks like this `echo json_encode(array('status' => 'true'));` Without the dataType: 'json', the result in the console looks like this `{"status":"true"}`

Comment: @Torben Then you should be able to forget about the loop and just access the data like this: `success : function (data) { alert(data.status); }`